# How i can send my Ethereum from kovan test network to Ethereum main network

Tags: network, transfer

I have Ethereum in metamask which is in kovan test network so now I want to withdraw them so I want send Ethereum in Ethereum main network so I send to any crypto application

Answer (score 0):

You cant send test ETH to other networks, Its for testing.